# How to concatenate jsx in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I have trouble adding padding to a component.
This is the current code (it works fine)

```
padding: ${props =>
  props.isMobile && props.variant === "a"
    ? Spacing.Large
    : Spacing.Small};
```

However I want the padding to only be top and bottom and the side to be 0, so I want to do something like this: (notice the 0's)

```
padding: ${props =>
  props.isMobile && props.variant === "a"
    ? 0 Spacing.Large
    : 0 Spacing.Small};
```

But it will give me a syntax error, what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding` takes a string value, so when you do the ternary statement, you need to make sure it's a string.

```
padding: ${props =>
  props.isMobile && props.variant === "a"
    ? `0 ${Spacing.Large}`
    : `0 ${Spacing.Small}`};
```

This will make sure the ternary is properly executed.